# The best way to return a variable in my app.blade.php Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel to build a CMS and I have a View Site button that's available in my main layout file (if that's how you call it) `app.blade.php`. This file is where I yield my content and load all my css and js files.

I want the link of the View Site button to be dynamic, based on a base url set in my settings table. I can retrieve the variable like this:

```
$settings = DB::table('settings')->get();

return $settings->base_url;
```

But my question is: how do i retrieve this in my view the **right** way?

I'm having trouble doing this because usually I link a method to a specific page with the `routes.php` file, but since the `app.blade.php` is available everywhere I'm unable to do this (I guess).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a [view composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views#view-composers). This is a function that can add data to a view every time it is being rendered. It makes the most sense to put your view composer inside of a service provider.

Make a new service provider inside `app/Providers`, then add your view composer inside of the `boot()` method.

ViewComposerServiceProvider

```
namespace App\Providers;

use DB;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ViewComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer('app', function($view) {
            $settings = DB::table('settings')->get();
            $view->with('base_url', $settings->base_url);
        });
    }
}
```

This would inject a variable called `$base_url` into `app.blade.php` every time it was rendered. Of course, instead of adding the view composer as a closure, you could move it out into its own class that just gets included inside the service provider, but this should give you the right idea.

Then just make sure to register your service provider inside `config/app.php`:

```
providers => [
    //All other service providers
    App\Providers\ViewComposerServiceProvider::class,
]
```

This is the preferred "Laravel way" to inject data into views every time they are rendered. This is the way that is the most flexible and scalable because it allows you to modify your views in really *any* way before rendering them. Laracasts has a really nice [free video](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/25) on the topic.

Comment: You can as an alternative use the Session facade along with middleware to achieve similar result without making provider file

Comment: @BartłomiejSobieszek that is definitely true, although probably not the preferred way of doing things as you would have to apply that middleware on every controller in order to inject the data into every route that returns a view. With a view composer, the data is injected automatically without ever needing to worry about applying middleware on your routes.

Comment: This seems like the way to do it, but something is going wrong. I followed all of your steps, but when I use `{{ $base_url }}` I receive an error saying that the variable is undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your `app.blade.php` in the root of the `views` directory or is it inside a subdirectory? The first `app` parameter that you pass into the view composer is the name of the blade file, so if it is nested in subdirectories you'd have to include those (I prefer dot notation), i.e. `parentDirectory.app`. If that is not the case, are you forgetting to put your service provider inside the `providers` array in `app/config`. If it's not that either, can you see if the service provider is being triggered at all? Do something like an `error_log` or `echo` something and see if you can tell if it fires

Comment: How silly of me... I forgot that my `app.blade.php` is in a layouts folder. I'm receiving a different error now though: `Trying to get property of non-object (View: /resources/views/dashboard.blade.php)`

Comment: That error means that somewhere in your view you are accessing a property on a variable that is not an object (most likely it's undefined). It *could* be our `$base_url` if your DB query is not correct and `$settings` is not defined. You can test this by running an `error_log`, `echo`, or `var_dump` on `$settings->base_url` in our service provider and see if it is getting the right data. If it is, it means that the error is not related to this and involves some other variable in your view. If it *is* the $base_url variable then there is a problem with `$settings = DB::table('settings')->get()`

Comment: I had to loop through the the `$settings` with a foreach first obviously:
`foreach ($settings as $setting)
            {
                $view->with('base_url', $setting->base_url);
            }` It's working now, thanks!

Comment: 'app' should be changed as 'layouts.app'.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create a helper function and use it in the view template.

In your `app` folder, create a file: `helper.php`

```
function getBaseURL()
{
  return \App\Setting::get()->base_url ;
}
```

Now in your blade template `app.blade.php`, you can get it like:

```
<a href="{{ getBaseURL() }}"> Visit Site</a>
```

You need to add this helper.php file to the composer autoload.

For that, in your compose.json file,

```
    "files":[
        "app/helper.php"
    ],
```

Add this in the `autoload` part.

Now do a `composer dump-autoload`